# Differences between Wind Waker and Wind Waker HD

Tags: version-differences, zelda-wind-waker, zelda-wind-waker-hd

I just bought *The Legend of Zelda: The Wind Waker HD* and since I already know the original, I've been thinking about following a walkthrough in order to find out about all the amazing secrets hidden within.

Aside from the graphics and controls, what are the differences? Will I be missing on anything if I follow a walkthrough that was written for the original?

Comment: Some Islands's locations like the Tower of the Gods, the Cabana and the Triangle Islands were changed for some reason. I am still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of changes that were made in Wind Waker HD. For the casual player, playing as intended, the two main differences to consider are the removal of the Tingle Tuner, and the addition of the Swift Sail.

The [Swift Sail](http://zeldawiki.org/Sail#Swift_Sail) is an upgrade to the sail that automatically sets the wind direction, and also allows the King of Red Lions to go significantly faster than with the normal sail. The Swift Sail can be found in the [Auction House](http://zeldawiki.org/Auction_House) on Windfall Island after beating Dragon Roost Cavern. It's not required, but it makes sailing so much faster and easier.

A change that affects fewer players, the removal of the [Tingle Tuner](http://zeldawiki.org/Tingle_Tuner), means just that: you cannot use the Game Boy Advance to assist your gameplay whatsoever (most walkthrough will probably assume that you do not have the equipment to use the Tingle Tuner anyway). The [Tingle Statues](http://zeldawiki.org/Tingle_Statue), however, are still in the game, but Link can now use his own bombs to reveal the chests they are in, instead of needing to use a Tingle Bomb.

Comment: There were also a number of glitches that were fixed, but I'm going to assume that you're not looking to speedrun the game

Comment: I won't be speedrunning. So an old 100% completion walkthrough will still work for a 100% completion run in the remake? That's all I needed to know, thanks.

Comment: @Nolonar Essentially yes, since you complete the auction house anyway. Though I _do_ recall something about the Tingle Statues still being in, even though the Tingle Tuner is out. Let me see...

Answer (score 20):

[This NeoGAF thread](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=689649) and [this Zelda Wiki page](http://zeldawiki.org/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_The_Wind_Waker_HD) have a pretty comprehensive list of changes, **some of which will defy walkthroughs for the original**. These are some of the bigger ones:

- The Swift Sail is a new item that can be obtained from the Windfall Auction. While using it, sailing speed is doubled and the wind is always at your back.
- The Tingle Tuner has been removed. Tingle Statues can now be collected with regular bombs instead of Tingle Bombs.
- Presumably related to the above, **the Knuckle figurine is now required in order to complete the Nintendo Gallery** (was previously optional).
- Tingle Bottles replace the Tingle Tuner. They can be used to send notes and Pictographs to Miiverse.
- The Picto Box can hold 12 pictos (was 3). Pictos are rated for quality the instant you take them, so you can delete and retake on the spot if it's not accepted.
- The Deluxe Picto Box is earned the instant you complete Lenzo's tasks; you don't have to bring him a Forest Firefly. Doing so just gets you a Joy Pendant.
- Pictographs can be uploaded and downloaded to and from Miiverse. This makes it possible to get pictographs of things you may no longer be able to get in the current file.
- The Deku Leaf has a glowing indicator on the ground to point where you would land if you drop.
- While firing bombs at sea, a line is drawn showing what path the bombs will take.
- **Magic Armour now drains your Rupees while in use**, instead of your magic.
- Items enemies drop last longer before disappearing.
- Items dropped by enemies at sea will fly towards you with okay accuracy, instead of appearing in a Treasure Sphere.
- Several item-based animations are significantly faster (e.g. Grappling Hook swing point attachment and chest salvage).
- The Wind Waker is always equipped on the D-Pad. While sailing, the Grappling Hook and Bombs are as well (with new icons), while the Sail is always equipped on the A button.
- Hero Mode is an option that can be toggled at any time before loading a file. It doubles damage taken and blocks recovery hearts from appearing.
- **Five of the eight Triforce Charts have been deleted and replaced with the actual shards.** Therefore, you only have to decipher 3 maps, not 8, saving you 1990 Rupees.
- Five new Treasure Charts have been added (42, 43, 44, 45, 46) to take the place of the removed Triforce Charts; they do not appear to lead to anything special.
- Forest Water lasts for 10 minutes longer (30 instead of 20), making it easier to complete the "water the withered saplings" sidequest.
- After the first time, Fishman advice can be read at any time without having to re-feed them.
- Getting hit while on your boat tends to not knock you into the water most of the time.
- You can change direction while swinging on a rope without having to stop.
- Enemies tend to have less invincibility after getting hit. This makes some swings capable of hitting twice.
- You can move while first-person aiming with several items.
- The "grab" and "climb" buttons for blocks have been merged, so you must walk into blocks for several seconds to climb them (like in the N64 games). This is pretty much a downgrade and a real curious decision.
- Treasure Spheres dropped by enemies will always contains their "spoil" item, should they have one.
- **The bottom of the Savage Labyrinth now contains the Hero's Charm, not a Heart Piece.** This heart piece is now found with treasure chart #46.

Answer (score 0):

There are 47 Treasure Charts instead of 46. Maybe its a part of the 5 extra they added or not, but so far I have 47, where everyone else says there are only 46.

Answer (score -1):

Another glitch is that the Treasure Map #15 is impossible to obtain AND leave the room with in B1 of the Forbidden Forest. The alternate action to crawl out of the hollow tree is not 'actionable' that is, it does not appear as an optional action EVER, on either side of the crawl hole.
Good thing it is just a treasure map, and completely optional (but I hate to leave any treasure behind in a dungeon, its not my style ;)

Answer (score -2):

I'm more of a retro gamer/collector myself, so I always go for the oldest version of the game regardless of graphics or advantages. But if you're looking for graphics, HD is MUCH better.(Though I still think there's something unique about GC Wind Waker's graphics that the HD version doesn't have.) Also, there's five less triforce charts, so it's way easier. The tingle bottle is a convenient touch too, even though I almost never use Miiverse. So if you're going for convenience and/or graphics, the HD version is the better deal.

Comment: I don't think this really address the differences very well.  The other answer describe in game differences rather than graphical and performance-like differences.

Comment: It's fairly easy to see the graphics have been altered. The question even states "**Aside from the graphics and controls, what are the differences**"

Answer (score -2):

Also, there's the swift sail, which is WAY faster and more convenient than the regular one, and the tingle tuner was removed so you don't have to go to the trouble of digging out and connecting your gameboy advance just to lay a special bomb for a side quest. The withered deku tree quest is easier, because of the extended expiration time on the forest water, and you don't have to crazily scramble around after breaking open a treasure sphere since items take longer to respawn. Link also gets knocked out of his boat less from attacks, which makes it MUCH less annoying to sail through a couple of areas. So yeah. Those are all the differences I can remember.

Comment: You can edit your own answers, don't post another answer to add onto your existing one.

Answer (score -2):

Here are some other changes. First and foremost, the firefly is not required to get the deluxe pictograph. Your deluxe pictograph can now take 12 pictures instead of 3. It tells you if the photo is a good or bad photo, and the sculptist can sculpt more than one figurine at a time. The boats bomb function has an extremely annoying location indicator, showing you where you are shooting. The leave shows you where you are going to land. The wind indicator is easier to use. Items and Map menu is changed. Dungeons seems to be easier (and I think slightly remodeled too) than on my GC version. Oh,  and the wind waker, bombs and grapple hook are more easily accessible. Seems like they just made the whole game (disappointingly) easier.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new that the other answers don't already have.